# Get encrypted column name with their encryption key and certificate in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I am using SQL Server 2008/2012.In my database I have a table which has encrypted column. The column is encrypted by using following query -

**Create the example table**

```
CREATE TABLE [HR].[Employees](
      [EmployeeID]      [int]         NOT NULL,
      [EmployeeName]    [varchar](50) NULL,
      [SSN]             [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
      [EncryptedSSN]    [varbinary] (200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(     [EmployeeID] ASC)
)
GO
```

**Set up the Master Key**

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY 
PASSWORD = 'T3stP@ssword'
GO
```

**Create the Symmetric Key and CERTIFICATE**

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE TestCert
   WITH SUBJECT = 'SSN Encryption';
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY HRKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = DES
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE TestCert;
GO
```

**Encrypt Data**

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY HRKey
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE TestCert;
Now we can update the EncryptedSSN column of our Employees table.

UPDATE [HR].[Employees]
   SET [EncryptedSSN] = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('HRKey'), SSN);
GO
```

I am **decrypting this data** by using the query -

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY HRKey
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE TestCert;
SELECT [SSN], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DecryptByKey([EncryptedSSN])) 
    AS 'Decrypted SSN'
    FROM [HR].[Employees]
GO
```

Here we give key/ certificate value hardcoded.

I am getting the encrypted column name with their table by this query -

```
SELECT stab.name Table_Name, sc.name Column_Name FROM sys.columns sc
        INNER JOIN sys.types st ON sc.system_type_id=st.system_type_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables stab ON stab.object_id=sc.object_id
        WHERE st.name='varbinary'
        AND stab.is_ms_shipped=0
```

And the key and certificate list by this query -

```
SELECT name, key_length, algorithm_desc, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.symmetric_keys;
SELECT name, subject, start_date, expiry_date 
FROM sys.certificates
```

Now I want to get which key/certificate belongs to which encrypted column SO I can apply decryption on that column without giving hardcoded value. Please help me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After search and try I found the solution that is  -

```
SELECT DISTINCT key_name(encryptedcol) FROM encryptedTable;
```

This query gives result the encrypted key which is belong to that column.

Answer (score 6):

I am using SQL Server 2016 .

Below here is the query to get all required Encrypted columns with key.

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName
    ,c.name AS ColumnName
    ,c.max_length
    ,k.name AS KeyName
    ,c.encryption_type_desc
    ,c.encryption_algorithm_name
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.column_encryption_keys k ON c.column_encryption_key_id = k.column_encryption_key_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE encryption_type IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question was for SQL Server 2008/2012, if you can not check your proposal on those versions, you should add as comment. (Still you can not, I know, but somebody can think that it is not useful, and he/she could downvote you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least using T-SQL built-in system functions and views.

Also, a column's type can be `varbinary` and the data there is not necessary to be encrypted.

If you want to build dynamic T-SQL statements and to avoid certificates and keys hard-coding, then you can create a `mapping` table. For example, something like this:

```
TableName
ColumnName
Certificate
EncryptionKey
IsSymmetric
```

It is not the perfect work-around (yes,you need to maintained the data), but if new columns are not encrypted constantly it may do the job.